# Generate a Web Service Client in WS-I compliance mode

Tags: web-services, magento, soap, ws-i

I'm trying to create a web service client using Visual Studio 2010.
The client works very well if I use the wsdl file in version SOAP V2.
When I set the property `WS-I Compliance` to `Yes` in Magento and recompile the web service client in VS2010, it doesn't work!!! Some methods disappear from the resulting WSDL file.

I've found the same problem if I generate a java web service client using the tool `wsimport`.

Any idea of what's happening?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue and instead of commenting out the catalogProductAttributeRemove, I actually looked into what was missing and added the additional sections to my wsi.xml file. Thanks to Juanma R. for pointing me in the direction of the file that needed to be corrected.

I referenced the entries for catalogProductAttributeCreate as a reference point for what other sections might need to exist to fix this. I don't really know anything about WSDL, just tried looking for what could be missing.

After I changed the file I refreshed all caches in Magento and confirmed the new entries were showing up in the WSDL file at /index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1. I then removed the web reference that was added to VS 2010 and went through the steps of adding the web reference again. This time after adding it I got no errors.

The version of Magento that I was patching is Magento Enterprise 1.12.0.2 but I expect it's applicable to other versions that show this same error with catalogProductAttributeRemove.

Here is a quick diff I ran of what I changed in the wsi.xml file:

```
*** Z:\mage-1-12-0-2.dev\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\etc\wsi - Copy.xml backup    Tue Jul 3 12:08:31 2012 UTC
--- Z:\mage-1-12-0-2.dev\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\etc\wsi.xml  Fri Nov 9 18:40:58 2012 UTC
***************
*** 1509,1520 ****
                  <xsd:complexType>
                      <xsd:sequence>
                          <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="result" type="xsd:string" />
                      </xsd:sequence>
                  </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
          </xsd:schema>
      </wsdl:types>
      <wsdl:message name="catalogProductCurrentStoreRequest">
          <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:catalogProductCurrentStoreRequestParam" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="catalogProductCurrentStoreResponse">
--- 1509,1540 ----
                  <xsd:complexType>
                      <xsd:sequence>
                          <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="result" type="xsd:string" />
                      </xsd:sequence>
                  </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
+ 
+           
+ <!-- Added by Matt Johnson 2012-11-09 to fix VS 2010 support of SOAP reference -->
+           <xsd:element name="catalogProductAttributeRemoveRequestParam">
+               <xsd:complexType>
+                   <xsd:sequence>
+                       <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
+                       <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="attribute" type="xsd:string" />
+                   </xsd:sequence>
+               </xsd:complexType>
+           </xsd:element>
+           <xsd:element name="catalogProductAttributeRemoveResponseParam">
+               <xsd:complexType>
+                   <xsd:sequence>
+                       <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="result" type="xsd:boolean" />
+                   </xsd:sequence>
+               </xsd:complexType>
+           </xsd:element>
+           
+           
          </xsd:schema>
      </wsdl:types>
      <wsdl:message name="catalogProductCurrentStoreRequest">
          <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:catalogProductCurrentStoreRequestParam" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="catalogProductCurrentStoreResponse">
***************
*** 1883,1894 ****
      <wsdl:message name="catalogProductAttributeCreateRequest">
          <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:catalogProductAttributeCreateRequestParam" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="catalogProductAttributeCreateResponse">
          <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:catalogProductAttributeCreateResponseParam" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
          <wsdl:operation name="catalogCategoryCurrentStore">
              <wsdl:documentation>Set_Get current store view</wsdl:documentation>
              <wsdl:input message="typens:catalogCategoryCurrentStoreRequest" />
              <wsdl:output message="typens:catalogCategoryCurrentStoreResponse" />
          </wsdl:operation>
--- 1903,1923 ----
      <wsdl:message name="catalogProductAttributeCreateRequest">
          <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:catalogProductAttributeCreateRequestParam" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="catalogProductAttributeCreateResponse">
          <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:catalogProductAttributeCreateResponseParam" />
      </wsdl:message>
+ 
+ <!-- Added by Matt Johnson 2012-11-09 to fix VS 2010 support of SOAP reference -->
+   <wsdl:message name="catalogProductAttributeRemoveRequest">
+       <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:catalogProductAttributeRemoveRequestParam" />
+   </wsdl:message>
+   <wsdl:message name="catalogProductAttributeRemoveResponse">
+       <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:catalogProductAttributeRemoveResponseParam" />
+   </wsdl:message> 
+   
      <wsdl:portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
          <wsdl:operation name="catalogCategoryCurrentStore">
              <wsdl:documentation>Set_Get current store view</wsdl:documentation>
              <wsdl:input message="typens:catalogCategoryCurrentStoreRequest" />
              <wsdl:output message="typens:catalogCategoryCurrentStoreResponse" />
          </wsdl:operation>
***************
*** 2760,2771 ****
                  <soap:body use="literal" />
              </wsdl:input>
              <wsdl:output>
                  <soap:body use="literal" />
              </wsdl:output>
          </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:binding>
      <wsdl:service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
          <wsdl:port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
              <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
          </wsdl:port>
      </wsdl:service>
--- 2789,2814 ----
                  <soap:body use="literal" />
              </wsdl:input>
              <wsdl:output>
                  <soap:body use="literal" />
              </wsdl:output>
          </wsdl:operation>
+ 
+ 
+ <!-- Added by Matt Johnson 2012-11-09 to fix VS 2010 support of SOAP reference -->        
+       <wsdl:operation name="catalogProductAttributeRemove">
+           <soap:operation soapAction="" />
+           <wsdl:input>
+               <soap:body use="literal" />
+           </wsdl:input>
+           <wsdl:output>
+               <soap:body use="literal" />
+           </wsdl:output>
+       </wsdl:operation>
+       
+       
      </wsdl:binding>
      <wsdl:service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
          <wsdl:port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
              <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
          </wsdl:port>
      </wsdl:service>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a mistake in the original Magento Core code, related to the operation "catalogProductAttributeRemove" (module core/Mage/Catalog).

To solve it, I've commented the following operation in the wsi.xml file of the module Catalog

```
 <!--wsdl:operation name="catalogProductAttributeRemove">
    <wsdl:documentation>Delete attribute</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:input message="typens:catalogProductAttributeRemoveRequest" />
    <wsdl:output message="typens:catalogProductAttributeRemoveResponse" />
</wsdl:operation-->
```

After that the automatic building of a Web Service Client using VS2010 works perfectly!.

Answer (score 2):

I included the diff into the wsi.xml from version 1.7.2 and uploaded it [here](http://esync.de/magento-wsdl-defect-catalogProductAttributeRemoveResponse).

So, if you can't read the diff correct, you can use this file directly.